# how to set imageview by taking the value returned from shared preferences

Tags: android, json

Hi friend i am getting the image from json in my main activity and sending it to my second activity using shared preferences. but i am not able to display the image in imageview that i retrieved from json

my main activity code where i am getting the image from json and sending to next activity using shared preferences.

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position,
                    long id) { 
String purtimage = ((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.largimage)).getContext().toString();
// Starting new intent

                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),CarDetails.class);
                Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                //intent.putExtra("image", largimage);
                editor.commit();
                startActivity(intent);
            }   
        });
```

this is my second activity where i am trying to display the image in image view.

```
prefs = getSharedPreferences("Share",
                    getApplicationContext().MODE_PRIVATE);

         String largimage = prefs.getString("image", "");
         ImageView limage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
         limage.setContentDescription(largimage);
```

please help me in fixing this

Comment: use picasso library.CHECK MY ANSWER

Comment: http://square.github.io/picasso/

Comment: check the answer it contains link also

Comment: its working so i accepted but image is not displaying so i am working on it. if you have any idea let me know

Comment: @ManojDB if it's working then why unaccept the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Use Picasso .Include this in android studio using compile `compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'`
 or include the jar file from [HERE](https://github.com/square/picasso).

then simply use this line

```
Picasso.with(context).load("largimage").into(limage);
```

Comment: its just going to next activity by removing my default image but not inserting the new image. if can help me with it will be help full for me thanku

Comment: @ManojDB can u give me your image link and also check if your image path("largimage") is not null

Comment: @ManojDB also i dont see where you are trying to save image to pref.You are commiting your editor without saving the image.Try like this                                     Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),CarDetails.class);
                Editor editor = prefs.edit();
               editor.putString("image", largimage);
                editor.commit();

Comment: can you give me your mail id i ll send a part of my work so that you can get a better understanding

Comment: @ManojDB it's hard for me to take out time for that.You have to try it by yourself .Sorry bro